# table changing height of the row every time i drop a draggable on them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so, i got a problem with a table. it has 3 tds that are the cells of the row and 3 of them are droppables from jquery, my problem is that everytime i drop a draggable on them the height of the cell changes and it changes the overall height of the table. i tried with the css property table-layout:fixed but its not working plz if you can help it would be awesome...
im currently using jquery, javascript, css, html with bootstrap, thanks in advance

table

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 tabla">
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                              <thead>
                                <tr>
                                  <th scope="col">Deportivas</th>
                                  <th scope="col">Culturales</th>
                                  <th scope="col">Otras</th>
                                </tr>
                              </thead>
                              <tbody>
                                <tr>

                                  <td>Ir a atletismo</td>
                                  <td class="td1"></td>
                                  <td>Ir al cumpleaños</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>

                                  <td class="td2"></td>
                                  <td>Ir al museo</td>
                                  <td class="td3"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>

                                  <td class="raya"><span class="raya-tb">&#8212;</span></td>
                                  <td class="raya"><span class="raya-tb">&#8212;</span></td>
                                  <td class="libro">Leer un libro</td>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

css of table

```
.tabla{
  margin-top: 15%;
}

table
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed !important;
}

td
{
  padding: 0;
}
```

and the javascript + jquery script

```
$("#draggable, #draggable2, #draggable3").draggable(
            {
                cursor: "move",
                helper: 'clone',
                revert: "invalid"

            }
        );

        $(".td3").droppable(
            {
                tolerance: "intersect",
                accept: "#draggable",
                drop: function(event, ui) {
                    $(".td3").append($(ui.draggable));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add these styles to css

```
td.ui-droppable {
   position: relative;
}
td.ui-droppable .ui-draggable {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So i finally gave up, trying to do the same process of putting the p draggable in to the td (cell) of the table and i wrap up a div with some text with opacity 0, then when the p is dragged into the dropper, the draggable goes to the div and because the div already has a text on it it doesnt change the size of the td. well 2 things i learned from this, tables with draggables do unexpected things and second always wrap your items on a div. thanks